# Modifying JSON inside bash loop using jq - reading/writing from files or store all data at vars?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, replace, jq

I have the following `JSON` template file - `tmpl.json`

```
{
  "locations": [],
  "name": "",
  "script": {
    "events": [
      {
        "description": "",
        "type": "navigate",
        "url": "",
        "wait": {
          "waitFor": "page_complete"
        }
      }
    ],
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "type": "BROWSER"
}
```

I need to use the above file as a template and add content into `.locations[]`, `.name`, `.script.events[].description` and `.script.events[].url` inside a loop dynamically and then use in the same loop the resulted `JSON` with `curl` PUT call.

The content of the `locations[]` which needs to be added is a static array in a separate `loc.json` file:

```
["LOCATION-577B","LOCATION-D7FF","LOCATION-8BE4","LOCATION-0CE9"]
```

While the values for other keys are calculated dynamically inside the loop.

Here is the way I manipulate the data to create a temporary `JSON` file for each iteration of the loop. $1 is the parameter calculated in the loop and then passed to the function to create temporary `JSON` which then is used with the `curl`.

```
jq --slurpfile loc "loc.json" \
        --arg URL "$1" \
        '.locations|=$loc[] |
        .name=$URL |
    .script.events[].url=$URL | 
    .script.events[].description="Loading of URL \"" +$URL + "\""' \
        "tmpl.json" >"$1-temp.json"
```

While the above works, I don't consider it a very clean or efficient way to deal with the problem. I need to iterate the loop over 1000 times which means creating 1000 temporary files locally and clean up afterward.

What would be a better way to deal with the problem? Read both the static locations array and the template files into variables via `heredocs` and use them inside the loop?
Or assign the resulted `JSON` output to a variable and then use it in the curl PUT call?

However, in the latter case, careful handling needs to be done of `whitespaces` and other special characters... The template file I've shown is just a fragment from the whole `JSON` file which contains way more key/values, but I need to modify only the keys outlined in the above.

**Update/clarification:** `$1` parameter used in the `jq` call is a single URL without http/https prefix. The list of URLs is calculated using another function/jq call and assigned to a bash var $URL_list. Then this var is used in the `for` loop to call the function which creates updates `JSON` for each URL.

The REST calls to also use `curl_combined_parameter` and `curl_combined_update_put` vars which are full requests with various parameters but they don't have a relation with the problem I am trying to solve.

So the cut-down version of the whole script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initiate the REST call which generates URL list


function get_url_list() {
# The function initiates REST call via curl with the $curl_combined_parameter, 
# pipes the result to `jq`, and assigns the resulted list to a var URL_list. 

    services_json=$(curl -s \
        --location \
        --request GET \
        "$curl_combined_parameter" \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer ${token}")

    # Now we filter the resulted `json` and get the list of sites
    URL_list=$(echo "$services_json" | 
                     jq -r ' map(.Body[].webServerName | 
                     select( (. != null and endswith(":443") ) and ( test("commerce|backoffice") | not ) ) ) | 
                     unique[] | .[0:-4] ')
}

function update_json() {
jq --slurpfile loc "loc.json" \
        --arg URL "$1" \
        '.locations|=$loc[] |
        .name=$URL |
    .script.events[].url=$URL | 
    .script.events[].description="Loading of URL \"" +$URL + "\""' \
        "tmpl.json" >"$1-temp.json"
}

push_changes(){
# take the resulted `JSON` generated from `update_json` and push it via curl PUT call
 curl --location \
        --request PUT \
        "$curl_combined_update_put" \
        -H "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
        -d "@$1-temp.json" >>"$1-updated.json"
}

for i in $URL_list; do 
update_json "$i"
push_changes "$i"
done
```

Suggestions are welcome. I just want to reduce creating unnecessary temp files and encapsulate all data inside the script.
Thanks.

Comment: if I understood the question correctly, you want to avoid the creation of 1000 temp files and send the output of `jq` directly with `curl`. if this is the case, `curl` can read input data from `stdin`, so you can pipe `jq` to `curl`, for example: `echo '[ 1, 2, 3 ]' | jq -c '{ foo: . }' | curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d@- localhost:8080`

Comment: How is $1 calculated?

Comment: $1 is a separate URL which is calculated from another REST call.
Think about this way - www.example1.com, www.new-example.com,  etc...
Every time in the loop it is a different URL.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Marco, thanks for your suggestion. What I quoted in my message is just part of the whole template JSON which is like 4K. Other keys, which stay static have a bunch of whitespaces and \/#%?: and other special chars in them. Will it be a problem with your solution?

Comment: @Invisible999 no problem at all. from `curl` prospective it is just like if it was reading from temp file, but instead the bytes comes from `stdin`

Comment: The trick here is that you have multiple items you want to replace, following different rules. That said, using `jq -n` you can enable your jq script to use `input` and `inputs` to read a line at a time, so you can feed as much data as you want/need into a single copy of jq.

Comment: I'd suggest raw-input mode so that data can be in a form that's easier for the shell to generate (like tab-delimited), and split into json objects after the data is already in jq.

Comment: ... to demonstrate that, though, we'd need to restructure your code to be longer be calling jq in a loop (but instead using the loop to generate a textual stream to send to _just one_ copy of jq), so we'd need to have the _existing_ loop be shown, rather than being given a calling convention that assumes one-function-call-per-item.

Comment: Can all the $1 URLs be precomputed (before calling jq)?

Comment: @peak - yes. The value of a ``$1`` is a single URL. List of all URLs is calculated at the beginning of the script using another function calling jq and assign resulted list to a var ``URL_list``. Then this var is used in the loop ``for i in $URL_list; do modify_json $i; done`` to create modified JSON from the template.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I've updated the problem description showing how the (cut-down version) script looks like. Just note, that the whole script is inside the bigger loop. For each tenant (list of tenants is 300-1000) one needs to obtain the list of sites and then using that list, generate another JSON for the final PUT curl call.

Comment: Great, thanks -- that's enough to make this much more answerable as it was before. As an aside, btw, see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: function declaration syntax -- `function foo() {` is very much a bashism, merging POSIX sh and legacy-ksh function declaration syntax in a way that breaks compatibility with _both_ the POSIX standard and legacy ksh. Because bash ignores the `function` keyword but it changes behavior in more closely ksh-like shells, `foo() {` is generally the better thing to write, so you aren't falsely implying behavior that only ksh provides.

Comment: BTW, as your url list is presently a string rather than a proper array -- how is that string formatted? Is it one item per line? (I'd prefer to read it into an array; avoids some bugs should your URLs have atypical characters or your IFS value be something unexpected).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Charles, thanks for insightful comments. Yes, you are correct regarding functions. Fixed that.
As far as the URL list - it has 1-10 entries, with the standard form - www.example.com or example-a.com, one entry per line, no special characters, etc.

Comment: Sure; I realize you expect your data to be in an expected format, but that's not a good reason to write code that's buggy if it _isn't_. I have a story I often tell here about a major data loss incident at a former employer caused by a shell script that assumed filenames would all consist of nothing but hex digits... until a buffer overflow overwrote a string in-memory, that memory was used to generate a filename, the filename contained an `*` surrounded by whitespace, and when the sloppily-written backup maintenance script tried to delete that file it deleted months of customer-billing too.

Comment: Just so I'm clear: The _desired output_ is one JSON file per URL, with `-updated.json` on the end, so the goal is just to get rid of the `-temp` files?

Comment: BTW, the one part of my answer I couldn't test was the `curl`s (not having your servers), but on doing a readthrough a few issues in that code jumped out. Please do note the recent edit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Charles, my code creates one JSON per URL and then uses that JSON to upload it to the server. The ``-updated`` is to collect status codes from the curl PUT to check them afterward. As a result, I am having (number of URLs +  one -updated file)*number_of_tenants files when the script runs. So if I have 5 URLs per tenant and 300 tenents the result is 1800 files created. From that 1500 are JSON files which curl used for upload and 300 - the status -updates files from these uploads.

My goal is to stop creating JSON files used for upload - generate them dynamically.

Comment: Right. That's what my answer does -- it no longer generates JSON files for upload, and only saves a JSON file with the result of each operation.

Answer (score 1):

First, we're going to want to make your `URL_list` be an array instead of a string:

```
readarray -t URL_list < <(jq -r 'map(.Body[].webServerName | 
                                 select( (. != null and endswith(":443") ) and
                                         ( test("commerce|backoffice") | not ) ) ) | 
                                 unique[] | .[0:-4]' <<<"$services_json")
```

Next, we're going to make only one copy of `jq` take all your URLs as line-oriented input, and emit one `JSON` document per URL on `stdout`, with a tab between the URL and the document itself:

```
build_updated_json_documents() {
  jq --slurpfile loc "loc.json" \
     --argjson tmpl "$(<tmpl.json)" \
     -c -Rr  '
    ($tmpl | .locations|=$loc[]) as $tmpl_with_loc |
    . as $URL |
    ($tmpl_with_loc |
     .name=$URL |
     .script.events[].url=$URL | 
     .script.events[].description="Loading of URL \"\($URL)\"") |
    "\($URL)\t\(. | tojson)"
  ' < <(printf '%s\n' "${URL_list[@]}")
}
```

...and pipe the resulting stream to a function that reads it line-by-line and does the curl requests, piping direct from the copy of `curl` that would otherwise be generating a temp file to the one that's coming up with your final result to be stored:

```
handle_each_document() {
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r url doc; do
    # first, ask our remote server to update this document for us
    # (would be nice if the server would do this in bulk, no?)
    # ...and then forward that request to the other server.
    curl --location \
         --request PUT \
         "$curl_combined_update_put" \
         -H "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
         -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
         -d- <<<"$doc" \
    | curl --location \
           --request PUT \
           "$curl_combined_update_put" \
           -H "accept: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
           -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
           -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" \
           -d- >"${url}-updated.json"
  done
}

build_updated_json_documents | handle_each_document
```

Comment: Charles, thanks for writing. I am trying to wrap my head around it. Could you help me to understand a couple of things?
First - in the second block, submitting ``URL_list`` as the whole array - how the ``$URL`` is getting assigned the current URL? I am looking at `` . as $URL`` and got lost there. 
The third block - why there are two entries of curl and how ``"$doc"`` var comes into the picture? I don't see any assignment here.

Comment: `IFS=$'\t' read -r url doc` reads a line from stdin, puts everything before the first tab into `url`, and puts everything on the line after the tab into `doc`. Because we pipe to this function from `build_updated_json_documents`, its stdin holds the tab-separated lines that function emits.

Comment: And the `printf '%s\n' "${URL_list[@]}"` is generating a line of input for each element in the array, so they're assigned by jq to `.` one at a time; `. as $URL` then grants a more readable name.